# hamburger is not working when i click. i have to drag for menu

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, hamburger-menu

This is the main activity where I have implemented the drawer and toolbar. I have tried all possible solutions on stack. I have not used the hamburger image 
I created the navigation view and added it in my xml:

```
public class NavigationMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    RoundImage roundedImage;
    ImageView profileImage;
    TextView uname,mail;

    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_menu);

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        /* Setting drawer in menu*/
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container,new HomeFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        /* Accessing database getApplicationContext( */
        db = new SQLiteHandler(this);

        HashMap<String,String> user = db.getUserDetails();

        String id = user.get("id");
        String name = user.get("name");
        String email = user.get("email");

        Log.d("Soulsystem", name);
        Log.d("Soulsystem", email);

        /*Access navigation header here to set name and to call the attributes of header*/
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        uname = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.rahul);
            uname.setText(name);
        AppController.getInstance().setClientConsultancyDetails(id,name,email);

        profileImage = (ImageView)header.findViewById(R.id.navigation_view_Image);
        profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                profile();
            }
        });

        // session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
            logoutUser();
        }

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()){

                    case R.id.contact:
                        contact();
                        break;

                    case R.id.logout:
                        logoutUser();
                       /* item.setChecked(true);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();*/
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void logoutUser() {
        session.setLogin(false);

        db.deleteUsers();
        Intent intent = new Intent(NavigationMenu.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    //call to Profile image fragment
    private void profile(){
        Log.d("NavigationMenu", "In profile Image view");
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new ClientProfile());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    }

    //call to Contact image fragment
    private void contact(){
        Log.d("NavigationMenu", "In profile Image view");
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new Contact());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drawe_menu, menu);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem item= menu.findItem(R.menu.drawe_menu);
        item.setVisible(false);
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try listening to toolbar

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
               drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        }
    });
```